# Automating Reseller commission

Tags: web-services

I have a web site that is a Seller to customer service. E.g: A seller is selling Item_a for £100, a customer then wants to buy this Item_a. Is there a way to automate a transaction so that If they sell the Item for £100, I would like 90% to go to the Seller and 10% to go to me for providing the service (some kind of a reseller commission).

Is there a way of automating this if you had hundreds of transactions taking place? could it be done with paypal, Google Checkout or another service?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is definitely possible. I know for sure you can in paypal, but the other services should be the same. Paypal may be the easiest however. The specifics of how you do this is a bit complicated and you should look into the api reference:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

also you can test out your code in the sandbox:

https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Just an FYI: Please don't use moderator flags to ask for retags. You can suggest edits yourself. Also, most people have the privilege to retag questions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: @NullUserException I don't think I flagged this post however, are you talking about a different post?

Comment: Yes. To protect your anonymity I posted this here. It is the first flag listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/949275 (only you and moderators can see this page)